# HP G62 225ca randomly white screen mostly when unplugged

Tags: graphics-card, display, power

I have a 20 months old HP G62 225ca laptop that have a strange problem. At anytime, the screen can turn completely white and stays white until I close the screen and reopen it. The problem happens more frequently when the laptop work on the batteries. Also, the computer is still perfectly working when the screen is white. I can plug it on and external screen and continue working on it as nothing has happened.

I would argue that the laptop somehow has difficulty to provide enough power to the screen. However, I do not know how I could correct the problem. I have searched for solution from HP website, but the troubleshooting area is very limited. I wasn't able to find anyone describing the same problem on Google.

**Edit**

I completely unmounted the laptop and did not find any evidence that one of the part has burned or broken. Also, the laptop now more frequently turn to grey screen. Other problems have arisen that may or may not be connected to this issue. Sometime the usb ports don't work, other time connecting the laptop to a tv is impossible (the laptop detect the tv, but no images are sent). It further consolidate my opinion about a problem of power distribution. I, however, have absolutely no idea how it could be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many things, but it sounds like the motherboard is failing. If it was just the screen then I'd suggest the ribbon cable but as your USB is going too then this suggests more. I don't think the power will be the option as typically it either has the power or doesn't - if it is a power issue, you would have posting issues when booting (sometimes it would boot other times not).

I would back it up now!

Comment: You appear to be right about this, I cannot confirm it since I don't have a spare MB, but I ran some tests and searched about motherboard failing on google and everything point out at that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it is no longer under warranty because you opened it up (so even if it was, that is probably voided now).  However, that would have been a good option.  (Back it up and ship it off for a free warranty repair.)

I agree that it is something on the mainboard that failing, likely in the graphics area.  Any repair is going to cost you more than the laptop is probably worth.

Doing a quick search on ebay ( http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=HP+G62+motherboard&_sacat=0&_odkw=HP+G62&_osacat=0 ) I find MB's for about $100 - $150

Searching Newegg, I see the whole laptop for $300 - $340.  Once it gets to that range, even if it's fairly young, I part it out for the useful components.